# Change install location for Microsoft store apps?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

I have recently thought about using Microsoft Store to download apps (Netflix); however, I am afraid that as long as I continue to download apps from the store, my main SSD drive will be out of memory - as it is 250GB big.

Is there any way to change the default location of Microsoft store apps?

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, for any whom may conecrn. 
The Microsoft store apps will be installed to a default folder the user choose. 
In order to change the location after install -

> click Start > Settings > Systems > Apps & Features:

[image: Click the app and choose 'Move']

[image: Click in the list box then select the drive where you like to have it moved]

**Please note, this won't work for universal apps that come built into Windows 10**.